# Pandas to_csv creating file with less rows than it should

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a large dataframe:

```
[880892 rows x 19 columns]
```

When I print it on screen, all cool. Seems perfect.

However, I want to make a csv out of it, so I'm using:

```
csv_out='/Volumes/GoogleDrive/Meu Drive/data.csv'
df.to_csv(csv_out)
```

When I do that, I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/santanna_santanna/PycharmProjects/teste.py", line 68, in <module>
df.to_csv(csv_out)
  File "/Users/santanna_santanna/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 1524, in to_csv
formatter.save()
  File "/Users/santanna_santanna/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/formats/format.py", line 1656, in save
f.close()
OSError: [Errno 5] Input/output error
```

Despite the error, Pandas does create the file as requested, however instead of having 880892 rows, it has only 36965 rows (checked on OpenOffice and double checked on Python). I tried that a few different times and I noticed that sometimes the number of rows grows a little, some other times it stays below this number. It makes me think it is something related to Pandas performance.

What is the problem happening here? Would someone have a suggestion to create this same csv in a way that works?

Comment: Do you have the file open somewhere else? Like in google drive?

Comment: Try writing to a local drive, so you can be sure google's synchronization doesn't interfere with panda's writing process

Comment: That was it, in a local folder worked perfectly. Thanks folks